# Form + nested list not showing after submit

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm just learning sencha touch 2, MVC. I would to make a simple form that get a value, pass to a PHP file (for an API call to a web-service), move to a Nested List and show results.
But, my app doesn't show nothing after submit... Value is captured correctly (I see it in console log).
Please someone could me help?

Consider for testing that for now I don't pass value, and my API call calls directly with a hard-coded value. In future I'll work to pass form value...

Thank you in advance!

This is "app.js"

```
Ext.application({
  name:                     'Appre',
  icon:                     'resources/icons/icon.png',
  phoneStartupScreen:   'resources/images/phone_startup.png',
  //tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
  glossOnIcon:          false,
  //profiles:           ['Phone', 'Tablet'],
  views :       ['Viewport','SearchCap','ElencoRistoranti'],
  models:           ['ElencoRistoranti'],
  stores:           ['RistorantiCap'],
  controllers:  ['SearchCap'],
  viewport: {
    layout: {
        type: 'card',
        animation: {
            type: 'slide',
            direction: 'left',
            duration: 300
        }
    }
},
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Appre.view.Viewport')
} // launch: function() {
}) // Ext.application
```

This is form "search cap"

```
Ext.define('Appre.view.SearchCap', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'appre-searchCap',
config: {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'cap',
                placeHolder: 'Cap' 
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Cerca',
                action :'searchCap',
                id:'btnSubmitLogin'
            }] // items
    }] // items
}, // config
initialize: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    console.log('loginform:initialize');
}
});
```

This is controller

```
Ext.define('Appre.controller.SearchCap', {
extend : "Ext.app.Controller",
config : {
    refs : {
        btnSubmitLogin: 'button[action=searchCap]',
        form : 'appre-searchCap'
    },
    control : {
        btnSubmitLogin : {
            tap : "onSubmitLogin"
        }
    }
},
onSubmitLogin : function() {
    console.log("onSubmitLogin");
    var values = this.getForm().getValues();
    console.log(values);
    var $this=this;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'cerca-ristoranti-cap.php',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            values: Ext.encode({form_fields: values})
        },
        success: function(response, opts) {
            var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            //Ext.Msg.alert('Contact Complete!', obj.responseText);
            $this.resetForm();
            Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Appre.view.ElencoRistoranti'));
            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('Appre.view.ElencoRistoranti'));
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
            console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
        }
    });
},
resetForm: function() {
this.getForm().reset();
},
    launch : function() {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm launch");
    },
    init : function() {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm init");
    }
});
```

And this is Nested List

```
Ext.define('Appre.view.ElencoRistoranti', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'appre-elencoristoranti',
config: {
    xtype: 'nestedlist',
    title: 'Cap',
    displayField: 'name',
    store: {
        type: 'tree',
        fields: [
            'id_restaurant', 'name',
            {name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true}
        ],
        root: {
            leaf: false
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'cerca-ristoranti-cap.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'restaurants'
            } //reader
        } // proxy
    },
    detailCard: {
        xtype: 'panel',
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },
    listeners: {
        itemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, element, post) {
            this.getDetailCard().setHtml(post.get('name'));
        }
    }
} // config
});
```

cerca-ristoranti-cap.php it's a simple function that returns an array like this:

```
{
"restaurants":[{
    "id_restaurant":"40",
    "name":"La Saliera",
    "zip":"00128",
    "lat":"41.7900229",
    "lgt":"12.4513128"
}, {
    "id_restaurant":"64",
    "name":"Osteria del Borgo",
    "zip":"00128",
    "lat":"41.7887363",
    "lgt":"12.5149867"
}]
```

}

Comment: Please can you to show the content of `cerca-ristoranti-cap.php` for can we help you. Thxs.

Comment: added response of cerca-ristoranti-cap.php, it's a simple function that returns a JSON...

Comment: Please could you to put JSON file?.

Comment: added.... it's last one code!

Comment: please,someone could help me? Thank you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @sineverba sorry for response a little late, but here something this how you want show,

**Viewport.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Viewport' , {
  extend : 'Ext.viewport.Default',
  xtype : "viewport",
  config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    style: 'background:#ffffff;',
    layout : 'card',
    autoDestroy : false,
    cardSwitchAnimation : 'slide',

    items: [
       {
          xtype: 'appre-searchCap'
       },
    ],
  }
})
```

**app.js**

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
})

Ext.application({
    name: 'myapp',
    requires: [
         'myapp.view.SearchCap',
         'myapp.view.ElencoRistoranti',
         'myapp.view.SearchElenco',
    ],
    controllers: ['SearchCap'],
    models: ['myapp.model.SearchCapModel'],
    launch: function() {
         Ext.create('myapp.view.Viewport')
    }
});
```

**SearchCapModel.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.model.SearchCapModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
         idProperty: 'id_restaurant',
         fields: [
             { name: 'id_restaurant', type: 'string' },
             { name: 'name', type: 'string'},
             { name: 'zip', type: 'string' },
             { name: 'lat', type: 'string'},
             { name: 'lgt', type: 'string'}
        ],
   }
})
```

**SearchCapStore.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.store.SearchCapStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
         model: 'myapp.model.SearchCapModel',
         autoLoad: true,
         proxy: {
             type: 'ajax',
             url : 'cerca-ristoranti-cap.json',
             reader: {
                   type: 'json',
                   rootProperty: 'restaurants'
             } //reader
         },
   }
});
```

**SearchCap.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.controller.SearchCap', {
    extend : "Ext.app.Controller",

    views: ['SearchElenco'],

    config : {
         refs : {
             elencoListContainer: 'elencolistcontainer',
             btnSubmitLogin: 'button[action=searchCap]',
             form : 'appre-searchCap',
         },
         control : {
               btnSubmitLogin : {
                      tap : "onSubmitLogin"
               }
         }
    },
    onSubmitLogin : function() {
            console.log("onSubmitLogin");
            var values = this.getForm().getValues();
            console.log(values);

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'cerca-ristoranti-cap.json',
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {
                         values: Ext.encode({form_fields: values})
                    },
                    success: function(response, opts) {
                            var obj = response.responseText;
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Contact Complete!', obj);
                            Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('myapp.view.SearchElenco'));
                            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(1);
                    },
                    failure: function(response, opts) {
                          console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                    }
            });
    },
    resetForm: function() {
            this.getForm().reset();
    },
    launch : function() {
            this.callParent();
            console.log("LoginForm launch");
    },
    init : function() {
            this.callParent();
            console.log("LoginForm init");
    }
});
```

**SearchElenco.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.SearchElenco', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'elencolistcontainer',

    requires: ['myapp.store.SearchCapStore'],

    initialize: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);

            var s = Ext.create('myapp.store.SearchCapStore')
            var notesList = {
                    xtype: 'appre-elencoristoranti',
                    store: Ext.getStore(s).setAutoLoad(true),
                    listeners: {
                           disclose: {
                                    fn: this.onNotesListDisclose,
                                    scope: this
                           }
                    }
            };
            this.add([notesList])
    },
    onNotesListDisclose: function(list, record, target, index, event, options) {
            console.log('editNoteCommand');
            this.fireEvent('editNoteCommand', this, record);
    },

     config: {
           layout: {
                 type: 'fit'
           }
     }
});
```

**ElencoRistoranti.js**

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.ElencoRistoranti', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'appre-elencoristoranti',
    id: 'appreElenco',

    config: {
       emptyText: '<pre><div class="notes-list-empty-text">No list found.</div></pre>',
       onItemDisclosure: false,
       itemTpl: '<pre><div class="list-item-title">{id_restaurant}</div><div class="list-item-narrative">{name}</div></pre>',
    }
});
```

**SearchCap.js** - View

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.SearchCap', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'appre-searchCap',
    id: 'appreSearchCap',

    config: {
          layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
          },
          items: [
               {
                 xtype: 'fieldset',
                 title: 'Cap',
                 instructions: 'Enter Cap',
                 items: [
                     {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'cap',
                        placeHolder: 'Cap' 
                     },
                     {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Cerca',
                        ui: 'confirm',
                        action :'searchCap',
                        id:'btnSubmitLogin'
                     }
                 ] // items
              }
         ] // items
    }, // config
    initialize: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            console.log('loginform:initialize');
    }
});
```

[image]

**I hope help you and if you have a dude please let me know. :)**

Comment: Thank you very very much for your big work! By the way, where i made mistake? I saw you slightly changed "structure" of my app (and surely your is better than mine!) Another thing, is there possibility to give you "+1", "some star", a "thank" or something? THank you another time!

Comment: Ok, if you consider that the response is good and accept and vote up. Thanks :).

Comment: I cannot vote up, minus than 15 of reputation :( btw clicked on "usefule". Btw, could you explain, referring my code, where is my error? I did'nt focused it, followed your code and (naturally) it functions.. but, what if i would use mine? Thank you!